# Does the scorecard have data to determine revenues for the purpose of the 90/10 rule?

Tags: collegescorecard

Are there any variables in the scorecard data set that would allow me to get at the ratio of for-profit institution's revenues that come from federal student aid sources?  Specifically, I'm trying to find 90/10 compliance ratios over time.  Does IPEDS have more info not included in the scorecard that would be more helpful?

Answer (score 1):

While Scorecard data do not address 90/10, these data are available on the FSA data center: https://studentaid.ed.gov/sa/about/data-center/school/proprietary .  Data from the FSA data center can be merged with scorecard data by matching six-digit OPEID